# Type casting issue in C# and wcf header in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I am now developing a WCF service using Visual Studio 2013. My service contains a custom header field must be passed. Field name is "lisenseKey" I developed it. WCF service is working fine. Now I am about to call my service to test. I added a service reference to client project. Now I am calling like this.

```
MyService.Myservice proxy = new MyService.Myservice();
proxy.LisenseKey = "xxxxxx";
Label1.Text = proxy.GetMessage(TextBox1.Text);
```

When I assign lisense key value like this, it is showing error with red underline that "Cannot implicitly convert type string to MyService.MyService.string". How can I type cast in this condition? Or is there any way to pass header ? And I do not know how to use "MessageHeader".

Here is my server side code. I am trying to consume "GetMessage" method.

```
//using System.ServiceModel;
//using System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher;
//using System.ServiceModel.Channels;
//using System.ServiceModel.Description;
//using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyservice
{
    [OperationContract]
    void DoWork();

    [OperationContract]
    string GetMessage(string name);
}

public class MyServiceMessageInspector : IDispatchMessageInspector
{
    public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
    {
        if(request.Headers.FindHeader("LisenseKey","")==-1)
        {
            throw new FaultException("Lisense Key Was Not Provided");
        }

        var lisenseKey = request.Headers.GetHeader<string>("LisenseKey", "");
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(lisenseKey))
        {
            throw new FaultException("Lisnse key is not valid");
        }

        if(lisenseKey!="12345x")
        {
            throw new FaultException("Lisense key is not valid");
        }

        return instanceContext;
    }

    public void BeforeSendReply(ref Message reply,object correlationState)
    { 
    }
}

public class MyServiceMessageInspectorBehaviour:Attribute, IServiceBehavior
{
    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase, Collection<ServiceEndpoint> endpoints, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
    }
}

public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
{
    foreach(ChannelDispatcher channelDispatcher in serviceHostBase.ChannelDispatchers)
    {
        foreach(var endpointDispatcher in channelDispatcher.Endpoints)
        {
            endpointDispatcher.DispatchRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(new MyServiceMessageInspector());
        }
    }
}

public void Validate(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
{
}
```

Comment: What's the type of LisenseKey?

Comment: In serverside . It is string

Comment: The error happens on the client so what's the type on the client? Include the namespace of the type.